# SQL Login Denied yet Login is sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, logins, active-directory

When I installed SQL Server 2017 Standard I installed it under my domain account and added it to the sysadmin role. I have then added the Domain Admins AD group to SQL and have deleted my domain account from SQL Server.

Now when I try to login my login fails with error 18456. All other accounts of the Domain Admins group are able to login.

I ran the following query and it says my domain account is `type= user`, `privilege= admin`, `mapped login name=domain account` and `permissions path=DOMAIN\Domain Admins`

```sql
Exec xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\USERACCOUNT', 'all'
```

Looking at the server logs it says:

> Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an
> infrastructure error. Login lacks Connect SQL permission. [CLIENT:
> <local machine>]

Comment: is the error the same to all logins that are members of the Domain Admins AD group or just yours?

Comment: Just mine. All other accounts can login. I even tested by adding a test account to the Domain Admins group and then tried logging in which worked.

Comment: Does the failure occur when connecting from a remote server and from a local elevated session?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft No, the error doesn't occur from remote server or elevated session. I didn't think to try either of those. It is only happening when locally on the server and running SSMS regularly (not  as administrator)

Comment: Then it’s UAC.  Normal Windows security strips the  admin group from your token when you aren’t running an elevated process.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Why is that if I add my domain account to the SQL server then it doesn't need to run SSMS in an elevated session? Why is it that no one else is the domain admin group needs to run SSMS in an elevated session?

Comment: Under UAC you’re still you, so if you have an individual sysadmin login you can connect.  And UAC is never active for remote connections.